# mysqli fect assoc usage to retrieve everything in a table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a user table that contain a lots more data, I wonder how can I improve my select code below

```
if ($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user ")) {

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["name"] . "<br />";
    echo $row["user_id"] . "<br />";
    echo $row["photo"] . "<br />";
        //.. a lot more column here

 }

}
```

Comment: and your problem is...? improve how? fewer lines of code?

Comment: @MarcB I think using fetch object in my case is better

Comment: why? `$row->name` is "better" than `$row['name']`? If you're worried about a few microseconds of cpu time saved because you only need 10 chars for the object version than 12 chars for the array version, you are **SO** totally optimizing the wrong thing in your code.

Comment: I'm working with SAP with JS, so object keep the workflow 'cleaner'

Comment: sap/js won't care HOW you wrote your php code, as long as the php output conforms to whatever they're expecting as output.

Answer (score 0):

I use this as a array: `` $user_info = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `database` WHERE 1)); ``
and to call it i use `$user_info['column']`